# Seperate Card Header and body borders

Tags: html, css

I have a card that looks like

[image]

I want it to look like

[image]

This is my html

```
<div class="card-bg w-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="p-4 d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <div class="d-flex card-hdr align-items-center justify-content-between" style="color: #fff;">
            <h4 class="m-0 h5 font-weight-bold">Welcome</h4>
            <div class="py-1 px-2 bg-grey rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center card-bd justify-content-center mt-4">
            ...
        </div>

        <form class="form-inline mt-4 justify-content-around">
            ...
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my css

```
.card-bg {
  border: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

I also have a couple other styles not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do separate styles for both heading and content .

To do that I have created a extra container for all the content and applied the style separately to it .

> Use styles according to need , here used styles are for demo only

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}

.font-weight-bold {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  margin:0 0 4px 0;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-bg w-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="p-4 d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <div class="d-flex card-hdr align-items-center justify-content-between" style="color: #fff;">
      <h4 class="m-0 h5 font-weight-bold">Welcome</h4>
      <div class="py-1 px-2 bg-grey rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="text-center card-bd justify-content-center mt-4">
        ...
      </div>

      <form class="form-inline mt-4 justify-content-around">
        ...
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/), you can use the class `card-header` and `card-body` and the `mb-1` to add margin-bottom on the header. Like following :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-header bg-success text-white mb-1">Card header</h5>
  <div class="card-body bg-primary text-white">
    Card body
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. You have to just style both containers separately.

```css
body{
  background:#000;
  color:white;
}

.box1{
  padding: 0 10px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.box2{
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-top:5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9c668c8ddc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card-bg w-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="p-4 d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <div class="d-flex card-hdr align-items-center justify-content-between box1" style="color: #fff;">
            <h4 class="m-0 h5 font-weight-bold">Welcome</h4>
            <div class="py-1 px-2 bg-grey rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i></div>
        </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <div class="text-center card-bd justify-content-center mt-4">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        </div>

        <form class="form-inline mt-4 justify-content-around">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML, CSS is kept to a minimum to you can debug it easier. I've just used the classes from Bootstrap.

[image]

You don't have to add `!important`, just keep the custom style after the Bootstrap one.
In here it's the other way around.

**Take a look at this DEMO:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
.card {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.card .bg-card {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container p-4">
  <div class="card border-0">
    <div class="card-header bg-card rounded text-white p-4 mb-1">
      <h5 class="card-title mb-0">
        Welcome
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body bg-card rounded text-white p-4">
      <p class="card-text">Duis convallis risus ut justo hendrerit venenatis. Duis condimentum imperdiet nisi non tristique. Duis velit dolor, molestie feugiat augue et, laoreet imperdiet eros. Donec tempus erat sapien, sed feugiat nunc iaculis lobortis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```